# Run script on login *as root* on Catalina

Tags: catalina, script, login

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842016/launch-shell-script-on-login-in-mac-os-os-x) question, a response details that `com.apple.loginwindow` login hooks can be used to run script as root on user login.

I have followed the instructions by using

> sudo defaults write com.apple.loginwindow LoginHook /Users/Shared/Test.sh

except nothing is executed on login. My script makes use of a small background process and nothing else and works by typing it into my terminal so I am lead to believe that it simply isn't possible anymore.

If this method (as it is already deprecated) no longer works, are there any method that currently work for running login scripts as root?

Comment: Have you tried adding it to your crontab?

Comment: @JMY1000 If by crontab you mean launchd agents, the answer in the link by mklement0 suggests it is run as the user logging in and not root.

Comment: I do not. I'll go ahead and post an answer.

Comment: @JMY1000 Sorry, I don't actually know how to use it. I'm looking it up now though.

Comment: Does it need to run at login of a specific user, or at login of the first user to login, or at boot time?

Comment: Yeah @nohillside makes a good point that crontab doesn't establish a difference. Also take a look at [this](https://www.macworld.com/article/2047747/take-control-of-startup-and-login-items.html)

Comment: @nohillside I want it to run for every user. Preferably at boot time but it honestly doesn't matter. As long as it is running when a user is logged in.

Comment: @nohillside In actual fact, would you know by chance if there _is_ a way to do it on login rather than boot? My script works fine as is but I feel I may want to add something in the future that will require it be run on login instead.

Comment: To be run as the user or to be run as root? As user is easy, just add the script as a login item. As root (or if you want to mass-deploy) it‘s more tricky, may be worth another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using `crontab`.

Open the root user crontab (this will create a new `crontab` file if you don't have it):

`sudo crontab -e`

Add you command, with the time you want it to run in front (if you want to do it at a specific time, you can use [this handy tool](https://crontab.guru)):

`@reboot /Users/Shared/Test.sh`

Exit and save the file.

That's it! Your command should now run whenever your computer starts up. While this isn't *technically* the same as on login, it should be enough for almost all intents and purposes.

Comment: Trying this now.

Comment: This works perfectly so thank you! May I ask if there is _also_ a way to do it on login rather than boot?

Comment: Unfortunately not that I know of, @nohillside might know of something that I don't.